# c# Very slow Gridview update.

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with several TextBoxes, Dropdown Menus and Checkboxes in each of the 80 rows and a OnRowEdit and OnRowDataBound Event tied to the grid.
This is what I do to update the grid:

1. ImageButton Click in the row switches to EditMode (7 seconds) and populates the checkbox for each row, according to the relation the selected row has with the others
2. ImageButton Click in the row saves the edited Data (13 seconds)

   - Row: The click event collects the control data and saves row data to SQL
   - Column: Loop through all rows, get the state of a checkbox and save it to SQL

I'm an autodidact and there are most likely things that con be improve. If somebody please could have a look and point out what the critical time consuming operation is and how to speed things up. - Thanks, Martin

OnRowEdit:

```
protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Gridview_Milestones.SelectedIndex = -1;
        int rowIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        SelectedMSRow.Text = Convert.ToString(rowIndex);
        SelectedMSRowValue.Text = Convert.ToString(Gridview_Milestones.DataKeys[rowIndex].Value);
        CheckBox CheckedOrNot = Gridview_Milestones.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("checkboxCustomerRequired") as CheckBox;
        LabelCRD.Text = Convert.ToString(CheckedOrNot.Checked);
    }
```

OnRowDataBound:

```
protected void OnRowDataBoundMS(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox CBTr = e.Row.FindControl("CheckboxTriggers") as CheckBox;
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                if (LabelCRD.Text == "True")
                {
                    TextBox TBresult1 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBoxDefaultDays") as TextBox;
                    TBresult1.Visible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox TBresult1 = e.Row.FindControl("TextBoxDefaultDays") as TextBox;
                    TBresult1.Visible = true;
                }
                DropDownList DDL1 = e.Row.FindControl("DDOwnerGroup") as DropDownList;
                DropDownList DDL2 = e.Row.FindControl("DDOwner") as DropDownList;
                Label LBL1 = e.Row.FindControl("LabelDefaultOwnerGroupEdit") as Label;
                Label LBL2 = e.Row.FindControl("LabelDefaultOwnerEdit") as Label;
                DDL1.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(LBL1.Text);
                DDL2.DataBind();
                DDL2.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(LBL2.Text);
                CBTr.Visible = false;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedMSRow.Text))
            {                    
                DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
                int myDataKey = Convert.ToInt32(rowView["ID"]);
                CBTr.Checked = SetCheckBoxTrigger(myDataKey);
            }
        }
    }
```

Saving Row Data:

```
protected void UpdateMilesStones(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateTriggers();
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedMSRow.Text);
        Label DataKey = Gridview_Milestones.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("LabelEditID") as Label;
        DropDownList DDL1 = Gridview_Milestones.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("DDOwnerGroup") as DropDownList;
        CheckBox CKB1 = Gridview_Milestones.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("checkboxCustomerRequiredEdit") as Checkbox;
        TextBox TB1 = Gridview_Milestones.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("TextBoxDefaultDays") as TextBox;
        SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("XXXXX");
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(@"Update ...", objConn);
        objCommand.Parameters.Add(".....")
        objConn.Open();
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        objConn.Close();
        Gridview_Milestones.DataBind();
        Gridview_Milestones.EditIndex = -1;            
    }
```

Saving Column Data:

```
protected void UpdateTriggers()
    {
        DeleteOldTriggers();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in Gridview_Milestones.Rows)
        {
            string DataKey = Gridview_Milestones.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckboxTriggers")).Checked)
            {
                SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection("XXXXXX");
                SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into EPC_Triggers (MilestoneID, triggeredBy) Values (@IDMS,@IDRow)", objConn);
                objCommand.Parameters.Add("@IDMS", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedMSRowValue.Text);
                objCommand.Parameters.Add("@IDRow", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(DataKey);
                objConn.Open();
                objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                objConn.Close();
            }
        }
        Gridview_Milestones.Columns[13].Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using classic asp.net or mvc ?

Comment: what's the datasource of ddl2?

Comment: Why is it so difficult? Try to use DataAdapter for your database provider.

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf: classic asp.net
@ TZHX: both DropDownLists are populated by SQLDataSource and one is linked to the other as a parameter

Comment: @GADeveloper: I'll try it and I tried it before, but does this bring some benefit in terms of speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are possible changes.

1) Opening SQL connection thrice (updatetrigger, rowdatabound and UpdateMilesStones). Please avoid that. Try to do in one operation only.

2) Use using block for SQL Connection [check this link](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)

3) You can also use index instead of findcontrol if column orders are going to be fixed.

4) You can also keep data in memory/cache and at the end you will save all the data in SQL.

Please try these things. It will definitely improve the performance.

Comment: Lots of input! Thank you. 1) Actually the SQL connection is build more often: i) to populate the checkbox which requires one connection per row ii) to delete old values iii) for every single checked row during saving(!) iv) Saving the GridRow Data... and maybe populating the DropDownLists that are fed by SQLDataSource also counts. So you are telling me to pack all the data coming or going to SQL connection into one DataTable that is stored as a session parameter? 2) I'll try it 3) I thought I use the index wherever I could, but I'll check that again 4)this goes with point 1)

Comment: Packing all update operations into a single SQL Connection improved a lot. But I can't find any reference that clearly states that Rows[index].Cells[0].Controls[1] wins in performance over Rows[index].cells[0].FindControl("TOTAL").

Comment: Regarding index, it might be negligible performance improvement but it's obviously it will be faster then findcontrol because that will iterate through all controls. Can you please accept answer if it looks good to you.